# Linking my FB page with the like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I just added the FB like button (html5) to my website page. Is there a way to link it so it notifies my personal FB page when someone likes my website?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

However, you could subscribe to the `edge.create` javascript event on your website, and connect this up so some server-side script that notifies you when someone has clicked like on your website.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/